# Почасовая выборка из PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Здравствуйте, разработчики!

Уже который день ломаю голову как сделать почасовую выборку из БД, но с максимальныйми и средними значениями в каждый час, кроме того по возможности стоило бы выводить и нулевые значения в конкретный час (для красоты). Дело усугубляется тем, что версия PgSQL - 8.3

Таким образом функция `generate_series` не работает. `WITH` тоже странным образом отказыватся работать как есть в примере. Функция `unnest` аналогично - не работает.

Последней попыткой было объединить массив и таблицу, например через `JOIN`, чтобы выполнить выборку всего массива без исключения и найти все вхождения из таблиц по заданному времени.

Таблица у меня следуюшая:

id | related | info | time |

Получается следующий запрос может выбрать общее количество в конкретный час:

```
SELECT date_part('hour', tbl.time),
       COUNT(tbl.id)
FROM table AS tbl
WHERE tbl.related = 'to something'
      tbl.info = 'info'
GROUP BY date_part('hour', tbl.time)
ORDER BY date_part('hour', tbl.time)
```

А хочется, очень хочется, получить среднее в конкретный час. Подозреваю, что все не должно быть таким сложным, но за подсказкой лезу к вам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть таблица содержащая записи о часах Hours
h
0
...
23

```
SELECT h, AVG(<Ваше Поле>) AS someData
FROM hours LEFT JOIN tbl ON hours.h = date_part('hour', tbl.time)
GROUP BY h
```

Comment: Спасибо натолкнули меня на правильную мысль. Дело в том, что в моем случае, и, видимо, я забыл об этом упомянуть, мне необходимо делать выборку не по среднему значению поля, а по среднему значению кортежей за выбранный час.

Answer (score 1):

Т.е. получается примерно такой запрос:

```
SELECT  h, COALESCE(AVG(tbl.c), 0) AS average
FROM  hours
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT  date_trunc('hour', tbl.time) AS st,
         COUNT(tbl.call_id) AS c
       FROM  table AS tbl
       WHERE tbl.related = 'to something'
         AND tbl.info = 'info'
       GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', tbl.time)
       ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', tbl.time)
     ) AS tbl ON hours.h = date_part('hour', tbl.st)
GROUP BY h
ORDER BY h
```

В данный момент я не в силах его пытаться упростить.